# Python Syntax error: blank space at end of line

Tags: python, syntax-error

Python beginner here, I'm modifying a piece of existing code (TwitterSearch on Github) to search Twitter for specific tweets that contain certain keywords using standard search API. I keep getting a Syntax Error, but it points me to blank space at the end of a line.

The thing is, the code worked once yesterday (as in I got the output I wanted) and then I tried to use it again and it keeps giving me SyntaxError.

At one point the error was at the end of the code - I deleted the last few lines and the error would simply move to whatever the end of the code was (but it always pointed at blank space rather than anything I had typed). Now it's moved to the blank space after the closing brackets following 'created at' (see below)
I've been consistently indenting the same way throughout, so I don't think it's an indentation error. For reference, I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

These are the last four lines of the code:

```
for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
    print:('@%s tweeted: %s' % (tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text']), (tweet['created_at']))  ^ **this is where the Syntax Error points to**
        
except TwitterSearchException as e
    print:('e')
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you come up with the `print:('string')` syntax? It's usually either `print 'string'` or `print('string')`, depending on the version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried removing `:` from your `print:(...` statement?

```
try:
    tso = TwitterSearchOrder()
    tso.set_keywords(['xx'])
    tso.set_language('en')
    tso.set_geocode('37.0902000', '-095.7129000', '1mi')

    ts = TwitterSearch(
            consumer_key = 'xxxx',
            consumer_secret = 'xxxx',
            access_token = 'xxxx',
            access_token_secret = 'xxxx'

        )


    for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
        print('@%s tweeted: %s' % (tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text']), (tweet['created_at']))

except TwitterSearchException as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried that and now the error has moved to the `except` in the second to last line (pointing at the  letter t)

Comment: try adding `:` after `as e`, if it won't works, check out the code in my updated post

Comment: The code does have a try statement - please see the main post which I have edited. Thank you.

Comment: it's working! thank you so much. was it an indentation problem in the end?

Comment: yes, it was, and that semicolon after the print statement, lack of it after except
also if it's solved, mark the answer as so please